# How do I get wget to download a cgi file behind robots.txt?

Tags: wget

As an example - http://aok.heavengames.com/cgi-bin/aokcgi/display.cgi?action=t&fn=22.

I found a way to get through the robots.txt restrictions, but even then, it just downloads a binary file that's unreadable by anything.

Answer (score 3):

```
wget --user-agent=Mozilla \
  "http://aok.heavengames.com/cgi-bin/aokcgi/display.cgi?action=t&fn=22"
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Robot-Exclusion.html) on gnu.org

> If you know what you are doing and really really wish to turn off the robot exclusion, set the robots variable to ‘off’ in your .wgetrc. You can achieve the same effect from the command line using the -e switch, e.g. ‘wget -e robots=off url...’.

Comment: Actually after actually trying this now, Ulrich Dangel's solution works perfectly because the website is 403 on unknown user agent's it seems.

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts using: --user-agent | robots=off with no output and by checking a hex dump of the output.

I had success - by sending the file output to HTML format by using the example below

Try this:

```
wget --user-agent=Mozilla \ -e robots=off "http://aok.heavengames.com/cgi-bin/aokcgi/display.cgi?action=t&fn=22" -O -O cgi-converted-to-htmlfile.html
```

**FYI** the ***--user-agent=Mozilla \ -e robots=off***  is all on same line

option **-e robots=off**
will disable honoring the servers robots.txt

option **-O cgi-converted-to-htmlfile.html**
will output the file as a html file format to filename

> cgi-converted-to-htmlfile.html

Good luck,
I  hope its what your looking for.